# How to use new Map with async/await?

Tags: javascript, nestjs

I have class with inject i18n service. I want to use it in new Map. Now^ I have error 'No overload matches this call'.

```
  public async getContent() {

    const a = new Map([
      [
        'AA',
        new Map([
            'desc',
            [
              await this.i18n.t('Hello')
            ]
          ]
        ])
      ]
    ]);
```

PS:

Works when the second Map return only one pair

```
    const a = new Map([
      [
        'AA',
        new Map([
          ['desc', [await this.i18n.t('Hello'), await this.i18n.t('Hello')]],
        ])
      ]
    ]);
```

But^ when I add new pair, it doesn't work

```
        new Map([
          ['111', 222]
          ['desc', [await this.i18n.t('Hello'), await this.i18n.t('Hello')]],
        ])
```

Comment: Why not await the result before and set it to Map once fulfilled? I'm not sure the Map can be used in this way.

Comment: I have big Map array.

Answer (score 2):

Actually this should be possible, your syntax is incorrect (missing `[..]`). Consider this simple example:

```
function fakeI18n(someStr) {
    return new Promise((resolve => {
        setTimeout(() => {
            resolve('translatedString')
        }, 200);
    }))
}

(async () => {

    const result = new Map([
        [
            'AA',
            new Map([
                ['111', 222],
                [
                    'desc',
                    [await fakeI18n('hello'), await fakeI18n('hello')]
                ]])
        ]
    ]);

    console.log(result)
})()
```

This will print:

```
Map(1) {
  'AA' => Map(2) {
    '111' => 222,
    'desc' => [ 'translatedString', 'translatedString' ]
  }
}
```

Comment: thanks, didn't see `Map` used in this way, will learn something new today :)

Comment: Added a question

Comment: You need to specify each pair inside `[...]`. See my update.

Comment: @VladimirGolub: any feedback?